# My Data is there in reducer but I am unable to get in mapStateToProps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

Reducer -

```
const INITIAL_STATE ={
    user: null,
    isAuth: false,
    isAuthResolved: false
}
const auth = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action)=>{
switch(action.type){
    case 'SET_AUTH_USER': 
    console.log('reducer',action.user)
    return {user: action.user, isAuthResolved: true, isAuth:!!action.user}
    default:
         return state
}
}

export default auth
```

Where I want to Access Data -

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux'

class ServiceApp extends Component {

    renderApplication = (auth) => 
        <React.Fragment>
            <Navbar auth={auth} />
            <Navbar auth={auth} id='navbar-clone'/>
            <Sidebar/>
            <Routes/>
        </React.Fragment>


    render() {
        const {auth} = this.props
        console.log('Props', this.props)
        return this.renderApplication(auth)

    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state =>  {
console.log('State', state)
    return{ 
    auth: state.auth    
}    
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ServiceApp)
```

I am not getting the issue Please Resolve it as Soon as possible.
Here, Data is perfectly there in Reducer, But in state it's not there

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Your `state` is not having the `auth` object . you need to modify the state like below

```
const INITIAL_STATE ={
auth :{
    user: null,
    isAuth: false,
    isAuthResolved: false
}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As I can see you are only passing mapStateToProps in your connect. `connect()`It provides its connected component with the pieces of the data it needs from the store, and the functions it can use to dispatch actions to the store.
so you should provide a function it can use to dispatch actions to the store.

for more information check this link [React redux documentation](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect)